# Working with processes, I don't get why this isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, process

```
foreach (Process pro in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    int i = 0;
    if (pro.ProcessName == "notepad")
    {
        i++;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);

    }
}
```

what this code supposed to do is making textbox1.text, "2" if 2 notepad is running etc., however it doesn't do anything at all.
I can't see any problem looking at this code, so I am here.

Comment: No matter how many notepad instances you have running, you will only ever output "1" to the text box as you are resetting the loop counter in every iteration of the loop...

Comment: to add on cpedros: move int i = 0; above the foreach statement and move textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i); below... And then you should also apply the other answers regarding casing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if no notepads is running - you code won't do anything. Probably it should write 0 to textBox?

I'll suggest rewriting code like that:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Select(p => p.ProcessName).ToList();
int count = processes.Count(name => String.Compare(name, "notepad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
```

You will have ability to debug easily and see which elements are in your processes list.

Moreover, your process could be "Notepad" not "notepad". Thus I replaced your equality check with String.Compare call.

Answer (score 4):

your process name might be "notepad.exe" or something...instead of doing

```
if (pro.ProcessName == "notepad")
```

try

```
if (pro.ProcessName.StartsWith("notepad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

This way you can isolate the problem, and figure out what the full text name is.

Comment: might not hurt to ignore case `.StartsWith("notepad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: According to MSDN Process.ProcessName does not include the exe extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx

Answer (score 2):

CWell, first of all, you should move the declaration of the variable outside of the foreach cycle.

And second, you should do as alexD and agent-j say, change the way you are comparing the string:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Process pro in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (pro.ProcessName.StartsWith("notepad", Stringcomparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        i++;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, you're right, actually I would've used Ivan Danilov solution, or something similar, probably a single line expression: textBox1.Text = Process.GetProcesses().Count(p => p.ProcessName.StartsWith("notepad")).ToString();